# How to handle multiple popup dialogs in Web Application

Tags: asp.net

What is the best way to handle multiple popup dialogs in ASP.Net Web Application? Trying I have approx 5+ popup dialogs to show in the main page. currently I am using the ModalPopUpExtender to display the first popup. Do I have to Create a (New Panel and ModalPopUpExtender) for every popup? All this code in the main page would make it very cluttered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about having a user control with one `modalpopupextender` exposing a `public enum property` to set the type of the popup. You can have 5 panels inside that `modalpopupextender` whose display/data are controlled by the enum property.

From the main page, you set the `enum` property before you call `usercontrol.show()` which will in turn call `mpe.Show();` after setting the visibility on the appropriate panel.

This way you will only have one user control on the main page and all the pop up logic is contained within it.

Comment: Doesn't the ModalPopupExtender property PopupControlID have to be set to the porper panel though?

Comment: Yes, you will have your panels inside that PopupControlId panel. You call userControl.Show(Panel1); (pseudo code). The type in the show method will decide which panel (in this case panel1) inside the PopupControlId panel is visible, bind data etc. Then call mpe.Show();.

Comment: Ok. I really like the idea and going to give it a shot. I may have a question or two after I develpe it unless everything goes totally smooth. thanks.